# I want to dynamically populate a value based on a date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Thanks in advance to anyone who might be willing to take the time to help out with this.

**Goals:**

- I am working on a high/mid-level plan template, and I would like to dynamically pull the sprint ID number into Row 1 based on the date in Row 2 (see the "Plan" screenshot below).

**Problems:**

- The Week Starting date in Row 2 is not always the start of a sprint, requiring logic to determine in which sprint that date resides.
- I cannot seem to get any combination of INDEX + MATCH + DATE/WEEK/MONTH to provide a result other than an error. I have tried at least 20 permutations with no luck.

**Setup:**

- I have set up a data table on a separate worksheet detailing the start and end dates for each sprint (see the "Data Table" screenshot below).
- The Week Starting date in cell G2 is being populated as the Monday of the week for the earliest date in Col C via the formula:

---

```
=MIN(C:C)+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(MIN(C:C)),1,0,6,5,4,3,2)
```

---

- The Plan is Sheet1, the Data Table is Sheet2.

**Callouts:**

- I have manually populated the Sprint ID numbers into Row 1 of the Plan to show the intended goal.

[image: Plan Image]

[image: Data Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should answer your question if I correctly understand it. This formula will look at the date in row 2 and determine the sprint based on your sprint start/end sheet. For simplicity, I just have this all on one sheet.

Formula in B1:

```
=INDEX($J$2:$J$4,SUMPRODUCT((B2>=$K$2:$K$4)*(B2<=$L$2:$L$4)*MATCH(ROW($J$2:$J$4),ROW($J$2:$J$4))))
```

Drag it across to achieve the correct sprint for each column.

[image]

Comment: You are a genius!  Thank you, this worked exactly as desired.